# border-image not displaying properly on mobile, not sure what to do

Tags: html, css

My site isn't optimized for mobile, but I would think border-image css would still work, no?

Here is my CSS code that is applied on a few elements:

```
border-style: solid;
border-width: 6px;
-moz-border-image: url(images/general/border.png) 6 repeat;
-webkit-border-image: url(images/general/border.png) 6 repeat;
-o-border-image: url(images/general/border.png) 6 repeat;
border-image: url(images/general/border.png) 6 repeat;
```

**Desktop view:**

[image]

**Mobile view:**

[image]

Comment: what is your mobile browser version?

Comment: I'm using an Android phone; I'm not entirely sure what browser type is actually running, but the icon says "Internet". I'm not sure how to check for the version.


**EDIT:** I did a quick search, "what browser am I using" in the search bar. Apparently I am using "Android 4" as my browser.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8x6Z9/1/ can you please test this in your mobile browser?

Comment: It displayed properly. I may have used an image where the center is not blank. I'm going to test it right now to see if that might fix the issue.

Comment: yes there you go, test it with the image i have given and you can check this fiddle too http://jsfiddle.net/qG4T2/

Comment: You can Post the Edit as answer, so it may help someone in the future.. hope you will post that as an anser :)

Comment: Oh boy... How do I do that? Hahaha. _sorry_

Comment: you have a button below your question post as answer, copy the edit part of yours and paste it

Comment: Thanks to this site, my post is broken. I can't post images now?

Comment: may i post the edit as answer with your permission?

Comment: Please do :)
Here are some example images:
http://i.imgur.com/Uq98qp6.png
http://i.imgur.com/FdthrS5.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was with the Border Image

[image]

Changing the Image to White space at Center helped and Mobile Version can be seen below

[image]

It works Fine

**Code**

> Android 2.1+ `(with -webkit- prefix)`
>
> Blackberry 7.0 `(with -webkit- prefix), 10.0+`
>
> Chrome 15 `(with -webkit- prefix), 16+`
>
> Firefox 15+ `(with -moz prefix)`
>
> Firefox for Android `(with -moz- prefix)`
>
> iOS 3.2+ `(with -webkit- prefix)`
>
> Opera 10.5+ `(with -o- prefix)`
>
> Opera Mobile 11.0+ `(with -o- prefix)`
>
> Safari 3.1–5.1 `(with -webkit- prefix) 6.0+`

**Examples of Border Images**

[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/8x6Z9/1/)

[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/qG4T2/)